# Issue referencing ECL Components

Tags: cme, ecl

Recently developed ECL provider and was able to see the ECL Components in the  mount point.

But when trying to add ECL Components as multimedia links, cannot save or check-in the Components.

Are we missing any required configuration?

I can see the source fine:

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ecl:6-aem-16094844113mb!2D;copy!2D;109.jpg_!2F;images-fls-file"></image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are we missing any required configuration?

I don't think so, but the id looks very strange to me, can you try with a simpler one?

Also, what error are you getting when trying to save the Component? Please update your question as this can help us pinpoint the problem more easily. But in any case, I suspect the complex ID is the cause of your problem. The ids of all the items and from various ECL providers I have seen so far are much simpler and are in the following format:

`ecl:{publicationId}-{mountPointId}-{actualIdOfTheAsset}-{subType}-{file}`

where the {actualIdOfTheAsset} is usually an int.

One other thing that might cause issues is reading the actual ecl item through the provider and this happens when you add a reference to it from a Component for example. The ecl item is then loaded implicitly so if an error occurres during that operation, you won't be able to save your referencing Component.

To verify this, try opening the actual ecl item from Tridion (using the tree navigation within a publication). If you encounter any errors there, update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Atila,I agree that the names looks little length but it follows the exact format you mentioned above 16094844113mb!2D;copy!2D;109.jpg_!2F;images name is configured like this with parent folder.
But the name doesnt look like impacting the components, i was able to add it to component as multimedia link and see thumbnail of image fine.On save and Check in,UI doees not show any error.We did some research on check-in in the event viewer and we are seeing below error related to search

Comment: Unable to index item: tcm:X-XXXXX-XX. Sending a request to the Search Engine at http://localhost:8983/tridion failed with the following response: The connection can not be authenticated. 
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing Errorcode: 865 User:Dmain/user
 StackTrace Information Details: at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.ThrowIndexingException(String hostUrl, TcmUri subjectId, WebException e) at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.AddToIndex(TcmUri subjectId) at

Comment: That search error is completely unrelated to ECL; it’s just a search configuration issue.

Comment: Hey Rick,the search issue mentioned was pointing at ecl stub folder tcm and shows up in event viewer while trying to add ECL as multimedia link and save the component.is it still not be place to look at? Nothing is being logged in Ecl log and what other place we should be looking at for more details to track down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Dispose method is throwing not implemented exception however this error didn't show up in logs until the IIS was restart.But once it was reset and fix was straight forward.

Comment: Glad you found out what the issue was. Please accept your answer so the question becomes closed.